# iOS Core Bluetooth time limit for execution after being woken up from suspended state due to a bluetooth event

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, ios-background-mode

The [programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW1) for Core Bluetooth states that

> Upon being woken up, an app has around 10 seconds to complete a task. Ideally, it should complete the task as fast as possible and allow itself to be suspended again. Apps that spend too much time executing in the background can be throttled back by the system or killed.

However, I have a use case where I am required to gather data from a peripheral indefinitly. The user of the peripheral decides when to turn of the device and stop sending data. I have specified the background execution mode to use bluetooth LE accessories and everything is working fine. My app is woken up and is actually able to execute for more than 10 seconds. I want to know why the 10 second limit is not stoping my app and whether I could run into issues later on.

In case there is infact a 10 second limit that might cause issues what would be a possible solution to the problem.

I expected my app to be suspended by the OS. I have looked into beginBackgroundTask but since I am not experiancing issues with the time limit I am not sure whether or not if that is even necessary.

Comment: First, if you are running your app under Xcode, there are no execution limits. If your device is using Bluetooth notify/indicate to send data then each time it does that would probably reset the timer.